# Apply styling to child element in <td> tags

Tags: jquery, html, css

Would like some help with styling first element in the  tag. I would like to add an cursor pointer effect to first element in my  tags.

Here is my code

```
<div class="cut-image-yellow">
<td class="col-md-1 " style="vertical-align: inherit;">
<span class="number-10 text-center" id="number-10-<?php echo $row['id_vnr']; ?>"><?php echo $row['cut10_vnr']; ?></span>
<img alt="" class="yellow-process-cut   process-<?php echo $row['id_vnrp']; ?>"  src="../../css/icons/vinyl-rolls/cut.png">

</td>
</div>
```

I would like an effect on  tag inside the  tag.

I tried this but i didn't worked.

```
<style>
        .cut-image-yellow>td>img:nth-child(1) {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>
```

How I can target the  inside the class "cut-image-yellow > td > img 
and `cursor:pointer` effect.

Many Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why do you have `td` inside `div`?

Comment: Just tried that but It didn't worked.

Comment: `td` is for table tags..

Comment: I can get rid of <div> class

Comment: Need to learn about what valid html is. Use a validator to check it

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is having the `td` tag inside of the `div` tag, as this works

```
.cut-image-yellow img:nth-of-type(1) {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

but this does **NOT**

```
.cut-image-yellow td img:nth-of-type(1) {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Also, if you change your `td` tag to another `div` then this also works

```
.cut-image-yellow div img:nth-of-type(1) {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```